# 2d plot complex numbers in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, complex-numbers

I have a matrix

```
b = [1+ 1i, 2 + 1i, 2+ 2i, 3 + 3i, 3+ 3i ; ...
     1.2 + 2i , 2+2i,  2.1 + 2.1i, 3+2.1i, 3.1 + 3.2i]
```

where `real(b)` is the `x` coordinate, `b(x,:)` is one experiment, and `imag(b)` is the `y` coordinate.

I want two things:

1. plot my experiments in a 2d plot as lines (but the points have to be in the right order)
2. plot my `y` (usually called`z`) coordinate as a surface over the axes `x` and experiment.

The problem is, that I want lines along the rows and Matlab mixes the coordinates of the complex numbers up and the line appears in a zig-zag all over the place.

The more basic problem is that I want to have bars from `x1` to `x2` at `y1` and I only came up with adding a data point `y1` at `x1` and `x2`. But at `x2` there is also `y2` which seems to confuse Matlab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For question (1), `plot(b)` is going to give you lines made up of the columns of `b`.  If you switch to using b-transpose, i.e. `plot(b')`,  you'll plot each row separately.

```
plot(b')
ylim([-4 0])
xlim([-0 4])
```

Question (2) requires a certain toolbox for the `resp` function?

Comment: Thanks for the solution, only thing is that it turns my results around 180 degrees. Plotting (-b') inverts the x-Axis. For my second question i just edited to make it clearer.

Comment: Still not entirely clear on question 2 - are you saying want to have an m x n matrix b of complex values, and then assign y = b.imag, x = b.real, and z = i, i being the row number?

Comment: No i just want to plot the different rows of the matrix over the y-Axis such that i get a surface plot and not a number of overlayed line plots.

Comment: I think we're saying the same thing.  Take a look at http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/visualize/representing-a-matrix-as-a-surface.html .  You probably want to use `surf` (or `mesh`), but I believe that requires you to first create an [x,y] grid - x will be your `b.real`'s, z's your arbitrary index, and then you can map `b.imag` against it.  I always have to experiment a bit with 3D plots in MATLAB since I do them so infrequently.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula#Applications_in_complex_number_theory) to convert your data from Cartesian coordinates to polar coordinates.

```
clear all; close all;

function [rho, theta] = polarize(z)
  rho = abs(z);
  theta = angle(z);
end

b = [1+ 1i, 2 + 1i, 2+ 2i, 3 + 3i, 3+ 3i;
1.2 + 2i , 2+2i,  2.1 + 2.1i, 3+2.1i, 3.1 + 3.2i];

[rho1, theta1] = polarize(b(1,:));
[rho2, theta2] = polarize(b(2,:));

figure
hold on
polar(theta1, rho1, 'b');
polar(theta2, rho2, 'r');

print('-dpng','euler.png')
```

Result in Octave:
[image: polar plot]

Comment: This one works too but my b gets quite long and thus i want avoid loops or addressing the rows individually. Thanks

Comment: Could you add an image representing sample data to the question?

Comment: I can save the data in any form, but complex numbers are good because i have data that come in by at fix angle values (e.g. every degree) and data that are at random angles. I have to map the two and with using complex numbers it happens automatically. 
Here is a picture: https://www.dropbox.com/s/33cgsic6j6k5dbx/Capture.PNG